# How turn my loop results into a list

Tags: python

I have no idea how to use put these results into a list and sort it using python3.

```
 def get_new(x):

    i = 0
    while i < 6:
        i = i+1
        print (x)
        x = (x*31334)%31337

get_new(7546)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to create a list and `append` the values of x. Then `return` this list from your function:

```
def get_new(x):
    lst = []

    i = 0
    while i < 6:
        i = i+1
        x = (x*31334)%31337
        lst.append(x)

    return lst

print (get_new(7546))
#[8699, 5240, 15617, 15823, 15205, 17059]
```

Comment: @Estela No problem. If this answered your question, don't forget to accept this answer to mark this question as solved

Answer (score 0):

For calculating and sorting the calculated `list`, do this using list `append` and `sort`.

```
def get_new(x):
    new_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < 6:
        i = i+1
        #print (x)
        x = (x*31334)%31337
        new_list.append(x)   # append the each new value of x to `new_list`
    return new_list

a = get_new(7546) # returns the unsorted calculated list
a.sort()          # sorting using sort() function
print (a)
#OUTPUT [5240, 8699, 15205, 15617, 15823, 17059]
```